# Cannot set up https on Microsoft Azure VM

Tags: azure, ssl, https, owncloud

I am trying to set up https to work with my owncloud hosted on a Microsoft Azure virtual machine (Ubuntu Server 14.04). I have gone through some tutorials I found on the web and also one person on the owncloud forums was trying to help for a while but the problem is still unsolved.

https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=26375&start=30

I am wondering now is there anything unusual about a Linux system that is hosted on Microsoft Azure? Because this SSL setup as far as I've learned should pretty much work out of the box. I am wondering either this has anything to do with the fast that I have added HTTPS frontend after the VM was created, not in the process of its creation. Anyway, I am listening to 443 port and I have SSL enabled, I have created the keys pair and turned on the SSL engine. I tried the following tutorials (and many more I can't recall):

https://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_source.html#web-server-configuration

https://serversforhackers.com/ssl-certs/

http://www.rojtberg.net/687/secure-owncloud-setup/

Also Debian man pages etc. I have no idea why I can't connect to my server using https. What can I try next?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, but the question should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow (it's not a programming question). First thing is to make sure you opened an endpoint for port 443. Other than that, I'd post to ServerFault, along with additional details of what you've done and what type or error(s) you're seeing.

Comment: I am listening on 443 and the endpoint is added. Ill post on sf, thank you.